# Setting proxy in RSelenium with Chrome

Tags: r, selenium, rselenium

How can I setup RSelenium (via Chrome) to use a proxy server with username/password authentication?

This is what I have so far (where ip, port, username and password get replaced by actual values).

```
## Run the Selenium server
selServ <- wdman::selenium(verbose = TRUE)

## Set browser options
eCaps <- list(chromeOptions = list(
                  args = c('--disable-notifications',
                           '--window-size=1280,900',
                           agent,
                           '--proxy-server=http://ip:port',
                           '--proxy-auth=username:password',
                           )))

## Create remote driver
rd <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L,
                   browserName = "chrome",
                   extraCapabilities = eCaps)

## Open browser window
rd$open()

## Navigate to page
rd$navigate("https://www.google.com")
```

No luck so far... any ideas?

Comment: Have the same issue. Have you find the solution?

Comment: @Mislav No not yet. The only way I’ve been able to deal with this is to take out the username/password authentication all together and instead, limit access to the server, based on the user’s IP address.

Comment: Yeah, for me it says "Static IP Authentication not enabled for this account.", so I have to find solution with username/password. I will post if I found it.